# How to assign ID to MessageListenerContainer without using @JmsListener

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-integration, message-queue

I am using spring integration in my application and using  @ServiceActivator rather then @JmsListener . I need to assign ID to MessageListenerContainer so that i can programmatically start and stop the container.

Can someone help me to understand how to set up id for messageListenerContainer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` is only used for `@JmsListener` containers since they are not declared as `@Bean`s.

For containers declared as `@Bean` the "id" is the bean name and you get a reference to it from the `ApplicationContext`. In your case:

```
context.getBean("messageListenerContainer", SimpleMessageListenerContainer.class)
```